# Relation between two definition of second cohomology groups.

Tags: group-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I have studied in The Schur Multiplier by G. Karpilovsky, that the $n^{th}$ cohomology groups as quotient groups of $n$-cocycles and $n$-coboundries. But when they are defining the second cohomology group, they are using the concept of a central extension. I can not see an explicit relation between these two. Please helps me.

Comment: It should be $H^2(G, A)$ where $A$ is the kernel of your central extensions. Read for instance, Brown's book "Cohomology of groups."

Comment: @MoisheKohan thanks for your reply, I have edited it and going to study the reference book by you.

Comment: @YCor Now I have edited it, thank you

Comment: Browns book, suggested by Moishe, is a good reference.  The connection between cohomology and central extensions is also in Weibel's book "Homological Algebra".  Weibel's book is a pretty fundamental reference that I think everyone should have on their shelf.